# Does derived class' member functions inherit virtualness from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Say we have the following two classes, A is the base class with virtual destructor and B is the derived class whose destructor doesn't have *'virtual'* qualifier. My question is, if I going to derive more classes from B, will B's destructor automatically inherit the virtualness or I need to explicitly put *'virtual'* before *'~B() {...}'*

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "create A" << std::endl;};
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "destroy A" << std::endl;};
};

class B: A
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "create B" << std::endl;};
    ~B() { std::cout << "destroy B" << std::endl;};
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C++ standard (section 10.3):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in
>   a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, *[...]*
>   then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared).

So yes.

Answer (score 6):

If base class method is `virtual` then all the subsequent derived class methods will become `virtual`. However, IMO it's a good programming practice to put `virtual` ahead of the method; just to indicate the reader the nature of the function.

Also note that there are some corner case where you might get unexpected results:

```
struct A {
  virtual void foo(int i, float f) {}
};

sturct B : A {
  void foo(int i, int f) {}
};
```

Here actually, `B::foo()` is not overriding `A::foo()` with `virtual` mechanism; rather it's hiding it. So irrespective of you make `B::foo()` virtual, there is no advantage.

In C++0x, you have [`override`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_overrides_and_final) keyword, which overcomes such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualness is inherited all the way down. You only need to specify it in the top base class.

This is true for destructors as well as normal member functions.

Example:

```
class Base { virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base\n"; } };
class Derived1 : public Base { void foo() { std::cout << "Derived1\n"; } };
class Dervied2 : public Derived1 { void foo() { std::cout << "Derived2\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Base;
    Base* d1 = new Derived1;
    Base* d2 = new Derived2;
    Derived1* d3 = new Derived2;

    b->foo(); // Base
    d1->foo(); // Derived1
    d2->foo(); // Derived2
    d3->foo(); // Derived2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
or I need to explicitly put 'virtual' before '~B() {...}'
```

No, you need not, although you can put virtual here to make code more clear for the reader. This applies not only for destructors but for all member functions.